# Find : $\int_0^{b}\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx$ where $b>1$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

Evaluate :

$I=\int_0^{b}\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx$ where $b>1$

My attempt :

I use integral by part : $u=\ln x$ $dv=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$
Then : $u'=\frac{1}{x}$ and $v=\frac{\ln \frac{x-1}{x+1}}{2}$

So :

$I=[\frac{\ln x\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}}{2}]_0^{b}$

$+\int_0^{b}\frac{\ln (1+x)-\ln (x-1)}{2x}dx$

My problem here is limit of integral because $b>1$ ?

And I can't complete the last integral !

Comment: A related computation is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535861/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-lnxx2-1-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Not similar , $b<\infty$

Comment: Becomes related for $b\mapsto \infty$.

Comment: OK sir , thank you very much

Comment: MMA says: $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{1}{4} b^3 \Phi \left(b^2,2,\frac{3}{2}\right)+b-\log
   (b) \tanh ^{-1}(b),0\leq \Re(b)\leq 1\land \Im(b)=0\right]$$

Comment: Thank sir , sir what is the $MMA$ how I can use it

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : That `ConditionalExpression` does not apply to the Problem as stated since the range of $b$ it requires, $0 \leq b \leq 1$, is incompatible with the Problem's $1<b<\infty$.

Comment: For the second integral, you may want to look into the Polylogarithm function - specifically of order 2.

Answer (score 1):

$
\begin{align}
\int_0^b\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2-1}~dx&=\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2-1}~dx+\int_1^b\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2-1}~dx
\\&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}+\int_1^b\frac{\ln x}{x^2\left(1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)}~dx
\\&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\int_1^b\frac{\ln x}{x^{2n+2}}~dx
\\&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\int_1^b\ln x~d\left(\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)x^{2n+1}}\right)
\\&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}-\left[\dfrac{\ln x}{(2n+1)x^{2n+1}}\right]_1^b+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\int_1^b\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)x^{2n+1}}~d(\ln x)
\\&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}-\dfrac{\ln b}{(2n+1)b^{2n+1}}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\int_1^b\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)x^{2n+2}}~dx
\\&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}-\dfrac{\ln b}{(2n+1)b^{2n+1}}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left[\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2x^{2n+1}}\right]_1^b
\\&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}-\dfrac{\ln b}{(2n+1)b^{2n+1}}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2b^{2n+1}}
\\&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}-\dfrac{\ln b}{(2n+1)b^{2n+1}}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2b^{2n+1}}
\end{align}
$

Comment: In case you were interested, the last sum can be rewritten as in integral:$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^2b^{2n+1}}=\int_0^{1/b}\frac{\text{artanh}(x)}x\mathrm{d}x$$